# Wrapping $http call with promise decorator

Tags: angularjs, decorator, q

I have an angular service that I was using to communicate with my back-end like this:

```
getMyBooks: function(userId) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $http.get('/api/users/' + userId + '/books')
    .success(function(data) {
      deferred.resolve(data);
    }).error(function(data) {
      deferred.reject(data);
    });
  return deferred.promise;
},
```

However after 6 or so of these functions the code started getting unwieldy.

So I attempted to refactor this using the decorator pattern, loosely copying the doubling decorator from here: http://javascript.info/tutorial/decorators

Giving me this updated code:

```
var bookService = function ($http, $q, $filter) {

  var deferredwrapper = function(f) {
      return function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        f.apply(this, arguments)
          .success(function(data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
          }).error(function(data) {
            deferred.reject(data);
          });
        return deferred.promise;
      }
  };

  var funcs = {
    getBooks: deferredwrapper(
       function(userId) { $http.get('/api/users/' + userId + '/books') }
    )
  };

  return {
    getMyBooks: function() { funcs.getBooks }
  }
};
```

However this is just causing loads of errors and returning undefined a lot. I guess I'm passing a function when I should be calling it or something but I'm completely lost on how to make this work

Comment: This is an anti-pattern. The all to common practice is called promise wrapping, and should be avoided as it serves no purpose and makes your code harder to understand. See JB Nizet's answer for a better explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're making your own life too complex. Just use promise chaining:

```
getMyBooks: function(userId) {
  return $http.get('/api/users/' + userId + '/books').then(function(response) {
    return response.data;
  }).catch(function(response) {
    return $q.reject(response.data);
  });
}
```

That said, your technique doesn't work because the function you passed as argument to deferredwrapper() doesn't return anything. And the wrapper expected the function to return a HTTP promise. Change

```
function(userId) { $http.get('/api/users/' + userId + '/books') }
```

to

```
function(userId) { return $http.get('/api/users/' + userId + '/books'); }
```

You made the same mistake when returning the service: you're assigning a function that doesn't do nor return anything to `getMyBooks`. Change it to

```
getMyBooks: funcs.getBooks
```